# How to pass dynamically created env var (vuecli-3) to npm run?

Tags: vue-cli-3

My objective is to be able to build micro apps from within one vue-cli project to have everything in one place. So far I'm building to different dist folders using dynamically created env var, like this:

```
"build:test" : "env APP_DIR=\"folderName\" vue-cli-service build && npm run deployTest"
"build:test2" : "env APP_DIR=\"folderName2\" vue-cli-service build && npm run deployTest2"
...
```

The `npm run deployTest` should upload the build. For now I have every path hardcoded in various deploy scripts.

Is there a way to pass the dynamically created `env` variable value forward to `npm run` like for example `npm run deploy --env APP_DIR` ? Or any other solution?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after doing some research and with help from this post [pass-an-argument-command-line-to-be-used-by-an-env-mode-file-during-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745648/pass-an-argument-command-line-to-be-used-by-an-env-mode-file-during-build?rq=1) I came with a solution, may not be the best one or the most elegant, but works for me:

```
"build" : "vue-cli-service build",
"build:test" : "export APP_DIR=\"folderName\" && npm run build && npm run deployTest"
"build:test2" : "export APP_DIR=\"folderName2\" && npm run build && npm run deployTest"
```

Like this I can use the `APP_DIR` variable from within the subsequent scripts by calling `process.env.APP_DIR`